# Protractor- getText() showing error in async/await

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Failing to perform getText() and use in expect condition using async/await. Following is the it block

```
it('Apply permission to a folder', async () => {
   await docsHomePage.clickProject();
   await projectsPage.projectCreateNewFolderAndSelect("AutoProject");
   await projectsPage.uploadFile('Aug2017.pdf');
   //uploadMessageElement = await projectsPage.getFileUploadSuccessMessage();
   let uploadMessageText = element(by.id('projects-upload-success-new'));
   expect(await uploadMessageText.getText()).toEqual('1 new Document created sucessfully');
        await projectsPage.clickFileUploadSuccessCloseButton(); 
});
```

Getting the following error:

```
2) Non Angular CLM Page Apply permission to a folder
Message:
Failed: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
Stack:
ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
at Object.throwDecodedError 
(C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium- webdriver\lib\error.js:514:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:519:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at UserContext.it (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\Downloads\protractor-initial-project-master\protractor-initial-project-master\specs\user-groups-permission.js:57:45)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From asynchronous test:
Error
    at Suite.describe (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\Downloads\protractor-initial-project-master\protractor-initial-project-master\specs\user-groups-permission.js:49:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sagar.ladwa\Downloads\protractor-initial-project-master\protractor-initial-project-master\specs\user-groups-permission.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
```

Getting similar issue when we tried to create a page-object.

Answer (score 0):

It's your console.log which is causing the issue. If you want to print the text you will need to `await uploadMessageText.getText()` there also.

This will likely be easier for you

```
let uploadMessageText = await element(by.id('projects-upload-success-new')).getText()
console.log('-----------------------------------'+uploadMessageText);
expect(uploadMessageText).toEqual('1 new Document created sucessfully');
```

Comment: @DublinDev- I have removed the console.log. Still getting the same error ......................................                                 let uploadMessageText = await element(by.id('projects-upload-success-new')).getText();
            expect(uploadMessageText).toEqual('1 new Document created sucessfully');

Comment: Can you tell what stage the execution gets to before it times out?